# How to connect Spring Boot application remotely in Visual VM?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jvm, visualvm, jvm-arguments

I am new to Visual VM, how to connect to Spring Boot application remotely in Visual VM?

Multiple instances are running as a `java -jar app.jar` with random ports. How to connect from Visual VM, I have root access to the remote system. Do I need to enable any security configuration?

In the local system, applications shows up automatically but when I entered remote system IP address it's prompting `Add JMX connection` and `Add jstatd connection`.

[image: VisualVM]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to specify the remote `IP ADDRESS` and expose the listening `PORT` while running the jar.

Syntax:

```
java 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=<PORT> 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<IP_ADDRESS>
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=<PORT> 
-jar app-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Example: Listening port is `6001` and available for remote ip address `192.168.0.23`

```
java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=6001 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.0.23 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=6001 -jar app-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

For More details about set up Visual VM https://github.com/M-Thirumal/installation_guide/blob/master/visualVm/visualvm_remote_set_up.md

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this dilemma with Spring Boot as well. But I was not using a jar. I passed the jmx arguments to maven to profile the application without having to build a jar first.

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-Xdebug -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9010 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9010 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost"
```

For more details, I documented my steps [here](https://blog.phillipninan.com/profile-spring-boot-with-visual-vm).